# Midrule in LaTeX output of Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, latex

I'm using Python Pandas.

I'm trying to automate the creation of LaTeX tables from excel workbooks. I so far have the script complete to create the following dataframe:

```
            Date        Factor A    Factor B    Total
Person A    01/01/2015  A           C           $220m
Person B    01/02/2015  B           D           $439m
                                    Total       $659m
```

I can use Pandas `.to_latex()` command to create a booktabs table from this, which is all fine.

My question is, is it possible to add a midrule just before the last row of the dataframe above to the LaTeX output?

Comment: As stated in the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_latex.html) `.to_latex()` returns a string. Could you please add this string to your question?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since pandas' [`.to_latex()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_latex.html) does not seem to deliver such an option I would to this manually by some string handling:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# use a DataFrame df with some sample data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((5, 5)))

# get latex string via `.to_latex()`
latex = df.to_latex()

# split lines into a list
latex_list = latex.splitlines()

# insert a `\midrule` at third last position in list (which will be the fourth last line in latex output)
latex_list.insert(len(latex_list)-3, '\midrule')

# join split lines to get the modified latex output string
latex_new = '\n'.join(latex_list)
```

Latex output without additional `\midrule`:

```
\begin{tabular}{lrrrrr}
\toprule
{} &         0 &         1 &         2 &         3 &         4 \\
\midrule
0 &  0.563803 &  0.962439 &  0.572583 &  0.567999 &  0.390899 \\
1 &  0.728756 &  0.452122 &  0.358927 &  0.426866 &  0.234689 \\
2 &  0.907841 &  0.622264 &  0.128458 &  0.098953 &  0.711350 \\
3 &  0.338298 &  0.576341 &  0.625921 &  0.139799 &  0.146484 \\
4 &  0.303568 &  0.495921 &  0.835966 &  0.583697 &  0.675465 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

Output with manually added `\midrule`:

```
\begin{tabular}{lrrrrr}
\toprule
{} &         0 &         1 &         2 &         3 &         4 \\
\midrule
0 &  0.563803 &  0.962439 &  0.572583 &  0.567999 &  0.390899 \\
1 &  0.728756 &  0.452122 &  0.358927 &  0.426866 &  0.234689 \\
2 &  0.907841 &  0.622264 &  0.128458 &  0.098953 &  0.711350 \\
3 &  0.338298 &  0.576341 &  0.625921 &  0.139799 &  0.146484 \\
\midrule
4 &  0.303568 &  0.495921 &  0.835966 &  0.583697 &  0.675465 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 5):

Put the accepted answer into a function for whoever needs it.

```
def add_hline(latex: str, index: int) -> str:
    """
    Adds a horizontal `index` lines before the last line of the table

    Args:
        latex: latex table
        index: index of horizontal line insertion (in lines)
    """
    lines = latex.splitlines()
    lines.insert(len(lines) - index - 2, r'\midrule')
    return '\n'.join(lines).replace('NaN', '')
```