Pandas style.to_latex: how to add a \cmidrule in the header?
I have mycsv.csv:
Nr,A,B,C
1,a,b,g
2,c,d,h
3,e,f,i

With this Phyton code:
import pandas as pd

testo = pd.read_csv("mycsv.csv")
columns = [
    ('','Something'),
    ('Multicolumn','A'),
    ('Multicolumn','B'),   
    ('Something else',''),   
]
testo.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(columns)
testo.head()
testo.style.hide(axis="index").to_latex("myout.tex",hrules=True,
                                           multicol_align='c')

I got myout.tex:
\begin{tabular}{rlll}
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Multicolumn} & Something else \\
Something & A & B &  \\
\midrule
1 & a & b & g \\
2 & c & d & h \\
3 & e & f & i \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

I would like to add a \cmidrule{2-3} in the headers:
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rlll}
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Multicolumn} & Something else \\
\cmidrule{2-3}
Something & A & B &  \\
\midrule
1 & a & b & g \\
2 & c & d & h \\
3 & e & f & i \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}

How can I do it?

maybe some hack like https://stackoverflow.com/a/32276740/2777074 ?

If you don't need any special python features but just need to get the csv file into latex, maybe the csvsimple package could be an alternative. It has some cool features to use tabularray to print the table.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Of course, I know about csvsimple, but since I have to apply other functions to the csv with Python is much simpler.

:) too bad - playing with tabularray would be much more fun!

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz There are things even tabularray can't do :D

Now you've destroyed the illusion of the almighty package :P

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz ahahah

As a quick and dirty hack, one could use https://stackoverflow.com/a/32276740/2777074 to smuggle a \cmidrule{2-3} into the code:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

testo = pd.read_csv("mycsv.csv")
columns = [
    ('','Something'),
    ('Multicolumn','A'),
    ('Multicolumn','B'),   
    ('Something else',''),   
]
testo.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(columns)
testo.head()
latex = testo.style.hide(axis="index").to_latex(hrules=True,
                                           multicol_align='c')

latex_list = latex.splitlines()
latex_list.insert(3, '\\cmidrule{2-3}')

latex_new = '\n'.join(latex_list)

print(latex_new, file=open('myout.tex', 'w'))



Thank you, it's bad pandas doesn't have something to manage it :D

@CarLaTeX It might very well have something build in for this, I normally stay well away from everything python related :)

Now you've destroyed the illusion of the almighty programming language :D

@CarLaTeX oh no :)
